# Circular reference in Window function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Hello Redshift experts,

Have a requirement to calculate values for a column which refers to a value from the same column on previous row.

For Eg.:

```
colA | colB | colC
-------------------
  10|      2|    20 (NVL(prev_row.colC, 0) + colA) * colB
  12|      3|    96
  21|      2|   234
```

Is there a way to get around this in a non-recursive way

Here are table and value sqls

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (colA int, colB int);
INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES (10, 2), (12, 3),(21, 2);
```

Thanks for your interest in helping me out here.

Comment: More data would help clarify what you are trying to do.  Also, how is the previous row determined?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for quick reply. Above logic is part of a bigger processing sequence. For the very first row on colC, there wouldn't be any prev row value, hence NVL.